# Default records per page on listviews

Tags: list-view

There seems to be an inconsistency in the default number of record per page on standard SFDC listviews.  On one particular production org, I see that when I am logged in with a sys admin profile, the default is 100.  But when I log in using a diferent, non admin profile, the default is 25.  This is for the same listview, the same records visible to both users.  Any idea what's going on here?  In addition, is there a way of changing it and making the change sticky?  You can change the default, but then it goes away next time you look at the listview.

Comment: I've checked the list view settings and also **Setup** options for each object. Like you, hamayoun, I don't see a way to change this default. It may be worthwhile for you to log a case and post this need as an idea to [Salesforce Ideas](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch "Ideas").

Answer (score 4):

This is a per-user setting. Each user can choose the size of the list views from 5-200 per page. This setting will persist for that user (except for limited broken list views, such as the class list view). There is no setting anywhere that allows admins or even normal users to configure it. This value persists across user sessions, meaning that this setting is indeed very sticky.