# Limit the number of records displayed on a listView

Tags: list-view, admin

i have a listView that display a number of records, and i want this listView to display only 40 records.
if there is 1000 records i want just 40 records selected randomly.
How can i do that?

Regards

Amir

Comment: Hello , please go through this discussion [Default records per page on listviews](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16577/default-records-per-page-on-listviews?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have the 40 records selected randomly in a list view.

You would need to use a custom component for this, using Lightning Web Components.

To randomise the order, you can use the `Math.random()` [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_math.htm#apex_System_Math_random) in Apex to generate random numbers and only display 40 randomly selected records.